Is it possible to shrink back a GoPro battery?
When I use a GoPro, batteries sometimes expand, I believe due to overheating, which is an issue as they can get stuck in the GoPro.
Is it possible to shrink back a GoPro battery? Or shall I just toss away the GoPro batteries that have expanded too much?

Example of a bloated battery (left battery is ok, right battery is bloated):

(that looks like a small bloating but it's enough to get stuck in the GoPro)

I suppose this is Li-Ion battery. And if it's bloated find a place for battery recycling and throw it there. And replace it with new/normal battery.
If you try to shrink it, you may set up spontaneous combustion of the battery.
Also if the battery is bloated like this it may spontaneously combust on its own.

No, it cannot be repaired and needs immediate disposal
Any human-detectable amount of swelling is already far too much. The battery is damaged beyond repair and is a serious safety hazard. It must be disposed of properly, and as soon as possible. It cannot simply be thrown away, but your locality will have a dedicated procedure for handling electronic waste and/or damaged lithium-ion batteries.

Romeo’s answer is certainly entirely accurate, and I’ve upvoted it, but I felt it lacked the “big No” that this question deserves.

You can always propose an edit to another user's answer.

@PhilipKendall That feels like too large an edit to make to another user’s voice.

The battery is dangerous.
There is no safe and sensible way to repair it.
It MAY not proceed to the "vent with flame" stage shown below for a long while, and maybe never. However, it also MAY do so at any moment.
The in-vogue name for these swollen batteries is spicy pillows
A look at the images provided by that link will give you an extremely good idea of the potential dangers if you continuie to use them. While a flaming ball of nearly impossible to extinguish fire can be fun to deal with (ask me how I know :-) ) having it decide to proceed to the popularly named vent with flame stage inside your GoPro is probably something you would rather avoid.
Spicy pillows - some examples:

Vent with flame - these are real world examples of what can happen next:

Images from Google Images.

Yes I want to know the backstory about the flaming ball of nearly impossible to extinguish fire :) I may keep it till July 4th then.

@FranckDernoncourt If you want a flaming ball of nearly-impossible-to-extinguish fire, there are safer / less-hazardous ways to achieve that.

@wizzwizz4 sure, but is it free?

@FranckDernoncourt Replacement lungs are fairly expensive, if you breathe in the fumes.

@FranckDernoncourt  Click the links in my answer. They take  you to many images. EVERY image is a link to a webpage. Choose suitably impressive photos and click through :-) !!! || Why the fumes are bad - THermal runaway || Formal testing || More!
